# Saving project file in Visual Studio 2019 reverts changes in the csproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 RC Version 16.0.0 (VisualStudio.16.Release/16.0.0+28729.10) and I'm finding that intermittently when I save a project file the changes to the project file are being undone.

This has proved more than a little confusing as NuGet packages I've added disappear, or updated ones revert to previous versions.

Likewise, if I've included files in the project they will then no longer be included after the save, so it looks like the changes are not getting to the csproj file correctly?

Is anyone else experiencing this and does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: same here. also on preview - latest

Comment: Happens on RTM for me, and latest .2 patch.

Comment: Still happens in 16.0.3. Often seems to be triggered after I do Manage NuGet Packages for Solution, then try to upgrade one or more packages. Usually closing and reopening Visual Studio will clear it up, but sometimes I end up having to edit in an external editor while it's closed.

Comment: I've been editing project files with notepad because managing NuGet packages within Visual Studio is now essentially useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be resolved in 16.1.0 Preview 2.0

Comment: I'm getting another weird issue in 16.1.0 Preview 2.0, it's now just not saving at all sometimes, the asterisk stays next to the name in the tab when I press Save, Save All or build the project/solution

Comment: Still happening in 16.0.4 for me.