# Context menu's 'Edit csproj' intermittently not working in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 has the very useful facility to edit the project's `csproj` file  without first unloading the project via the context menu (or 'right click menu' to aid the search feature):

[image: Edit csproj option in VS2019]

However, I'm finding this isn't working intermittently, a lot of the time it just does nothing when I click the option.  Later it will start working again without restarting the project.  This is for a solution with multiple .NET Core Web projects and multiple .NET Standard libraries.

Does anyone know the cause of this?

(Possibly related: I've also been having issues with saving a csproj file causing my changes to be undone [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55500027/1879019).)

Comment: This context menu isn't even appearing for me. I'm on 2019 16.0.3. Did you need to do anything in order to have it show up? Working in a .NET 4.5. WebForms app..

Comment: @DennisDyallo I think this is possibly a .NET Core specific feature - for full .NET you should be able to open the context menu (i.e. right click) on the project, select 'Unload Project' and then right click on the project again and choose Edit [projectname].csproj.  Once you've completed your changes you need to right click on it again and reload the project